# $scope.$watch triggered with same old and new value when ng-if used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've found strange behavior in AngularJS. Looks to me like a bug but maybe it's reasonable.

I have some value that I pass to my directive as attribute. Inside this directive I watch the parameter with `$scope.$watch`. Turns out that if I put `ng-if` on this directive with same parameter in condition the `$watch` will be triggered with wrong old value (old value == new value).

I need to know when the value really changed (to distinguish from initial run when `$watch` is triggered without change). If this is not a bug, then how can I know if old value was different from current one in my directive?

[Here is the fiddle to show the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/pz1kmtyj/3/)

HTML Code:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model='myValue'>
        <option>1</option>
        <option>2</option>
        <option>3</option>
    </select>
    <check-change value="myValue"></check-change>
    <check-change value="myValue" ng-if="myValue==3"></check-change>
</div>
```

JS Backend:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myValue = 1;
});

myApp.directive('checkChange', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div>{{result}}</div>',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        controller: directiveController
    };
});

var directiveController = function ($scope) {
    $scope.$watch('value', function (newVal, oldVal) {
        $scope.result = 'Watch launched, result: ' + (newVal == oldVal);
    });
};
```

Comment: You should always post relevant code here at SO. People should not need to go to offsite resource to help you. remember links rot

Comment: @Satpal You're right. Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer I got from Angular JS collaborator Narretz:

> When the element gets destroyed via ng-if, it's scope and therefore the watcher on it is also destroyed. When the element is rendered again, the watcher is initialized again - which means it's called with the same values, because it triggers the exception.

Full thread [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12823)